# Is the phrase "anecdotal evidence" an oxymoron?

Tags: phrases, oxymoron

If evidence is empirical then surely anecdotes can't be evidence can they?

Comment: Rather than an oxymoron it might be better to consider it a synonym for  *indirect evidence*, *weak evidence*, or quite possibly both.

Comment: They are evidence....just not be best kind of evidence.

Comment: If the anecdote, report, or account is based upon, concerned with, or verified by personal observation or experience, as opposed to theory or pure logic, then it would meet the definition of empirical.

Comment: Anecdotes connected with reputation can qualify as evidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to answer the question in the title, an "oxymoron" is a figure of speech constructed of self contradictory elements. "Wise fool", "square circle", and "cool heat" are all oxymorons. On the other hand, an anecdote is a story, often short and containing an element of humor, but which nonetheless can be true, while evidence is a fact or observation offered in support of an assertion. The two words do not have opposite meanings, and therefore, "anecdotal evidence" is not an oxymoron.

But comparing the definition of evidence quoted above (from Wikitionary, cf. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evidence) with the definition of "empirical" from the same source, viz.

> 1 Pertaining to or based on experience.
>
> 2 Pertaining to, derived from, or testable by observations made using the physical senses or using instruments which extend the senses.
>
> 3 (philosophy of science) Verifiable by means of scientific experimentation.

I don't find any inherent conflict which would demand that anecdotal evidence could not also be empirical evidence, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Note that "anecdote", in this sense, does not mean "amusing story", but rather it means a piece of data gathered outside of any sort of rigorous data-collection strategy. If you notice that you pass a chartreuse barn every day as you drive into work, that's an anecdote. It tells you nothing about how many chartreuse barns there are in the world (or even along that route), but you know there's at least one. Look up "black swan" (the theory, not the movie).

Or a more "real" example. Alexander Fleming noticed that some contaminant in a petri dish had killed the Staphylococcus bacteria that had been growing there. This proved nothing, as the contaminant could have been anything, and there were several chemicals that could kill the bacteria. It was an "anecdote". But (after much rigorous experimentation) his observation proved to be the key to discovering penicillin.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it an oxymron, because [anecdotes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anecdote?q=anecdotes) **can** be real.

> 1. A short amusing or interesting story about a **real** incident or person
>
> 1.1 An account regarded as unreliable or hearsay

(Oxford)

> An anecdote is a short and amusing but serious account, which may depict a **real/fake** incident or character

([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdote))

---

*Anecdotal evidence* is used in contrast to *scientific evidence*. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence):

> The expression anecdotal evidence refers to evidence from anecdotes. In cases where small numbers of anecdotes are presented, there is a larger chance that they may be unreliable due to cherry-picked or otherwise non-representative samples of typical cases.
>
> The term is often used in contrast to scientific evidence, such as evidence-based medicine, which are types of formal accounts. Some anecdotal evidence does not qualify as scientific evidence because its nature prevents it from being investigated using the scientific method. Misuse of anecdotal evidence is an informal fallacy and is sometimes referred to as the "person who" fallacy ("I know a person who..."; "I know of a case where..." etc. Compare with hasty generalization)

Comment: I think of it more under the rubric of "a man down the pub told me". But as you say, anecdotes _can_ be true. Eye-witness accounts of the Chelyabinsk meteorite the other day are anecdotal, are they not? No repeatable scientific experiments there. But we would hardly doubt that it happened, even without the footage.

Comment: @DavidPugh: Exactly. In fact, most people put anecdotes under that rubric, some people restrictively so; hence the OP's confusion about `anecdotal evidence` being an oxymoron.

Comment: You need to state that "anecdote", in the medical/scientific sense, does not mean "amusing story", but rather data gathered outside of a rigorous "experiment".

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, *evidence* is presented in order to establish a proof or likelihood. A proof is attained by testing the evidence, which does not have to be true itself (hence the need for the test). So we can have "unreliable" or "false" evidence. (Or lots of other adjectives).

Further, "anecdotal" evidence is not in itself unacceptable as support for an argument, but the process of testing which follows its presentation should take its nature into account (as David Pugh suggests above).

Answer (score 0):

But you can anecdotally refer to the firmest evidence there can be.

> I heard the head of the Nobel Committee say he thought X should get the prize.